# Android-model load error

Tags: android, emacs

My Emacs version is 23.3.1, I am want to setup an android develop environment. I download [android-mode.el](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/tree/master)

and modify .emacs to load it;

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")
(require 'android-mode)
(custom-set-variables
 '(android-mode-avd "test")
 '(android-mode-sdk-dir "/opt/android-sdk/"))
```

when loading that file, it has error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/htang/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, cl-lib
```

I know the cl-lib is new feature since emacs24 or higher, how can I resolve this problem to make it work on my Emacs23.3 version?

Comment: Why not just install Emacs24? If you don't have root, you can still build from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can install cl-lib (for older Emacsen) from GNU ELPA.